# When the animation restarts, it cuts off images before the animation advances by a certain amount

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, sass

I created a marquee animation. It works okay, but when it restarts, it doesn't display all the chips. I noticed that when I widen my screen, the number of disappeared chips is greater.

```
.chipsbar {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto 0.85rem;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 1.35rem;
}

.chipsbar1 {
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite forwards;
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: fit-content;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1.35rem;
}



@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1.35rem));
    }
}
```

```
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="chipsbar">
                <div className="chipsbar1">
                    <img className="chip" src={shield} />
                    <img className="chip" src={soccer_white} />
                    <img className="chip" src={shield} />
                    <img className="chip" src={crown} />
                    <img className="chip" src={m_blue} />
                    <img className="chip" src={soccer_blue} />
                    <img className="chip" src={m_green} />
                </div>
                <div className="chipsbar1">
                    <img className="chip" src={shield} />
                    <img className="chip" src={soccer_white} />
                    <img className="chip" src={shield} />
                    <img className="chip" src={crown} />
                    <img className="chip" src={m_blue} />
                    <img className="chip" src={soccer_blue} />
                    <img className="chip" src={m_green} />
                </div>
                {/* Add more chipsbar divs here */}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I attempted the following solutions:

1. I added more chips, but the issue persisted.
2. I added more numbered chips bars within the 'chipsbar,' but they overlapped each other when the animation restarted.
3. I adjusted the animation duration, but it only affected the duration of the empty screen where the chips were supposed to be.